# Simple copying file c program returns corrupted file when using the combination fgets() and fputs(). It does work with getc() and putc()

Tags: c, file, stdout, stdin, fgets

The following program takes a file attached to `stdin` and copies it to the file attached to `stdout`.
If I use `fgets()` and `fputs()` the file copied is corrupted but when I use `getc()` and `putc()` all is fine.
Why is that?

Here's the code followed by the command I type on the terminal:

```
int main(int arg, char *argv[]) {
    int c;
    char buff[1024];
    char *p;
   
    while ((p = fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin)) != NULL) {
        fputs(buff, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Command typed:

```
./buff < cat.jpeg > cp_cat.jpeg
```

After that the file `cp_cat.jpeg` is corrupted.

Comment: `jpeg` is a binary file, you can't use `fgets` and `fputs` as these are intended to work with text strings (terminated by zero byte). You can use `fread`/`fwrite` though.

Comment: It works with `getc` and `putc` because you're reading/writing the file byte per byte including null bytes. With `fgets` and `fputs` you're reading/writing the file like a text file line by line, which makes no sense whatsoever with a jpeg file. Furthermore `fputs` stops writing as soon as a null byte is encountered which also contributes corrupting your output file.

Comment: How are you expecting `fputs` to know how many bytes to write?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons for the copied JPEG file to become corrupted:

- the files are open in text mode on a legacy system where line ending sequences are translated both from the input stream (removing CR in CR/LF pairs or possibly all CR bytes) and in the output stream (translating `'\n'` to CR LF pairs).  On such systems, `stdin` and `stdout` are in text mode by default and you must use non-standard APIs such as `_set_fmode(_O_BINARY)` to change this. Yet this would also corrupt the JPEG file when using `getc()` and `putc()` so you probably use macOS or another unix system.
- `fgets()` / `fputs()` cannot be used to copy files that contain null bytes because the null bytes stored by `fgets()` into the buffer are interpreted by `fputs()` as the end of the string causing the rest of the buffer to be ignored. There is no work around for this problem. To bufferize the copying process, you can use `fread()` and `fwrite()` to read and write blocks of bytes, and you must make sure the streams are operating in binary mode.

Here is an example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buff[1024];
    size_t nread;
   
#ifdef _MSC_VER 
    _set_fmode(_O_BINARY);  // default to binary I/O
#endif

    while ((nread = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, stdin)) != 0) {
        if (fwrite(buff, 1, nread, stdout) != nread) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error writing to stdout: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```